# javascript error: Expected 'html' and instead saw 'script'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#footer').css('top', $('#text').outerHeight() + 125 + 'px');
</script>​
```

Using jquery, but always get an error at line 1 char 2 if i check it in jslint.

Any idea?

Comment: If that's a ".js" file, you don't put `<script>` tags in those. It should be 100% JavaScript code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dennym/GK2br/ and its no js file, it a script in a html site

Comment: @xdazz: It can be, if you either give it just the code or the whole page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `script` tags are not part of the JavaScript. JSLint is for processing just JavaScript text. You only use it on this bit:

```
$('#footer').css('top', $('#text').outerHeight() + 125 + 'px');
```

JSLint will allow you to post HTML pages with embedded script tags in them, but you have to post more than *just* the script tags. For instance, it's okay with this:

```
<html><body><script>
$('#footer').css('top', $('#text').outerHeight() + 125 + 'px');
</script></body></html>
```

...other than not liking the fact that I haven't defined `$` (just because I threw that together).

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the `<script>` tags in the JavaScript section of JsFiddle (or in an external .js file).

Fixed Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GK2br/6/

Answer (score 0):

The "tolerate HTML fragments" JSLint option will suppress that warning. That will let you lint HTML files with embedded JavaScript that aren't full HTML documents. This can be helpful if you're dynamically loading HTML fragments and injecting them into elements.

For instance, you might have a few jQuery UI tabs whose contents are loaded dynamically from separate files. Each of those files might just contain the contents of what would otherwise be a div tag in the main HTML document. If, for whatever reason, those HTML fragments contain JavaScript that you need to lint, selecting the option will suppress the complaint about expecting to see the `<html>` tag.